# SQL query syntax (variable stays empty)

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to output a simple list with all the usernames registered on a single e-mail address in our database. The SQL queries necessary for it shouldn't be too hard, but apparently they are too hard for me - here's my issue:

```
$sql = "SELECT emailaddress FROM ".db_prefix("accounts")." where acctid = '$mailid'";
$mailadress = db_query($sql);
```

That one's working just fine - I'm declaring `mailid` in a earlier part of the code, and with that query I can output the e-mail adress (for debugging) of the currently logged in user without any problems. Fine so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM ".db_prefix("accounts")." where emailadress ='$mailadress'";
$charakterliste = db_query($sql);
```

Here's the issue: `$charakterliste` seems to stay empty, even though I'm pretty sure my syntax is correct. **var_dump()** and **print_r()** don't return anything that would point towards the array/variable containing something.

I've double checked and executed a similar query directly in the SQL database and found no problems there - all the fields I'm calling do exist, and the DB connection is fine too. I guess something is wrong in my syntax for the second SQL query? I'd want to list all the names saved in the `$charakterliste` afterwards with a **foreach** loop, but as of now there doesn't seem to be anything to list saved in there, although there should be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use prepared statements, please!

Comment: does the first query return an **array**, so your value `$mailadress` is infact an array whose content is infact in `$mailadress[0]` or `$mailadress['emailaddress']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the column 'emailadress' exist?

Maybe it's 'emailaddress' with two 'd'?

According to your first line of code it should be 'emailaddress'.

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM ".db_prefix("accounts")." where emailaddress ='$mailadress'";
$charakterliste = db_query($sql);
```

Comment: Exactly that was the issue - quite embarassing for me, but thanks to all of you nonetheless :)